# Mysql where 1= 0 confusion

Tags: mysql, select

In simply sql book, there is portion of code mentioning if I use `where 1 = 0`, i can safely add an OR conditions like:

```
WHERE
   1=0
   OR name LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR billaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR shipaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
```

I didnt get it why when i use `where 1 = 0` i can safely add an OR statement

Can i just use something like below?

```
WHERE
   1=1
   OR name LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR billaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR shipaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
```

I understand that `where 1=1` is a shortcut to add an And statement.
I understand that because `where 1 =1` will return true.Can i use it for `Or` statement too?
Istill didnt get the part `where 1 = 0`
Any explaination would be great.

Comment: Note that for readability you can also just use `where false or` & `where true and`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the type of boolean operations you're working on. If you want to add a variable number of `AND` statements, then you use a statement that invariably evaluates to true, such as `1 = 1`. On the other hand, if you want to do the same with `OR` statements, then you should use a statement that evaluates to false, such as `1 = 0`.

Let's say you have a boolean variable `x` with an indeterminate truth value (it might be true, or it might be false. You don't know.) Now, if you find the value of `x AND false`, you get `false`, regardless of what the value of `x` is.

On the other hand, if you look at `x OR true`, you'll get `true`. Again, this is regardless of the truth value of `x`.

In your statement, you want the hard-coded value to have no effect on the logic of the query. Since `false OR a OR b OR c` is logically equivalent to `a OR b OR c`, the hard-coded statement has no effect. In the other case, `true AND a AND b AND c` is equivalent to `a AND b AND c`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses [short-circuit boolean evaluation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

As soon as the result resolves to a definite TRUE or FALSE MySQL stops evaluating the rest of the rows.

`TRUE OR ? OR ?` will always be TRUE, so MySQL will only look at the first item and not test anything else.
`FALSE AND ? AND ?` will always be FALSE, so again MySQL will not look at the other tests.

This has the (unintended) side-effect that MySQL will never look at your table with the LIKE, but instead return all rows in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM atable
WHERE
   1=1                         /* <--- this makes the whole OR set always true*/
   OR name LIKE '%Toledo%'     /* therefore the like tests are never done     */
   OR billaddr LIKE '%Toledo%' /*and all rows are returned */
   OR shipaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
```

In this query:

```
SELECT * FROM atable
WHERE
   1=0                          /* false OR ? has an unknown outcome so */
   OR name LIKE '%Toledo%'      /* MySQL has to evaluate the LIKE tests */
   OR billaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'  /*only some rows will be returned*/
   OR shipaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
```

This works exactly in reverse with `AND`

Answer (score 0):

> Can i just use something like below?

```
WHERE
   1=1
   OR name LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR billaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
   OR shipaddr LIKE '%Toledo%'
```

that will return every row (since it's always true), so no...