# criteria api where 1<>1 clause

Tags: java, criteria-api

I want the query not to return any values. I can't just not query database, so I'd like to add some unreachable condition to predicates, something like 'where 1 <> 1'. But the CriteriaBuilder.equal() doesn't allow to do that. Is there any way to reach the goal?

Thanks.

Comment: try with the 1=0 for more detail see this post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145809/mysql-where-1-0-confusion/6145827#6145827][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145809/mysql-where-1-0-confusion/6145827#6145827

Comment: @Pratik, the problem is how to write the condition in criteria api. The condition itself is not a problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

```
CriteriaBuilder.notEqual(CriteriaBuilder.literal(1), 1)
```

Although, if you *know* that this shouldn't execute, then using expressions might not be optimal on some RDBMS, if the database can't peek at bind values. I don't know how to do create a JPA Predicate with an inlined `1 <> 1` SQL expression, though...

Answer (score 8):

Javadoc from CriteriaBuilder: "Create a disjunction (with zero disjuncts). A disjunction with zero disjuncts is false."

```
CriteriaBuilder cb..
Predicate itsFalse = cb.disjunction();
```

And then generated SQL depends about implementation, Hibernate produces 0=1. Why I prefer this method over other alternatives, is:

1. According documentation it fits perfectly to this use without
   additional arguments and you kind of guess what it does from name.
2. It is short.

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
CriteriaBuilder.isTrue(CriteriaBuilder.literal(Boolean.FALSE));
```

Comment: I don't think there are any other technologies, short of digging round in the implementation classes of a particular JPA implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```java
criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(false));
```

or

```java
Specification<TheEntity> specification = (root, query, cb) -> cb.isTrue(cb.literal(false));
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation, why you think that these lines solve the issue? What is the difference between bove proposals?