# Laravel with relation returning inaccurate result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to make a query to get all of the Interviews and get the company name in the companies table. I only want to return the name column in the company table.

I ran a query log and noticed that my relation was returning a weird query.

***Laravel Version 6.5.2***

**What I had originally**

```
$interviews = Interview::select('title', 'slug', 'subtitle', 'posted_date')
                                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                                    ->with(['company' => function($query) {
                                        $query->select('id','name');
                                    }])
                                    ->get();
```

**What I'm using now just to test if the relation was working:**

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

$interviews = Interview::select('title', 'slug', 'subtitle', 'posted_date')
                                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                                    ->with('company')
                                    ->get();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

**Company Model:**

```
public function interview() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Interview', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Interview Model:**

```
public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'id', 'company_id');
    }
```

**Result:**

```
select `title`, `slug`, `subtitle`, `posted_date` from `interviews` where `interviews`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc

select * from `companies` where 0 = 1 and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null
```

I am trying to figure out why it is returning `where 0 = 1` and not the actual model.

Also, is there a way to only return one of the fields like I above?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145809/mysql-where-1-0-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. You have to specify the `id` and `company_id` in your original query for it to work.

```
$interviews = Interview::select('id', 'title', 'company_id', 'slug', 'subtitle', 'posted_date')
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  ->with(['company:id,name'])
  ->get();
```